# Discord.js Get Status from Message

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

Hi I'm trying to make my Bot change its status from a message, and also set it with quick.db so if it restarts it changes back to the sotd. For example the message would be something like : Song of the day: "Wild Reputation" from the Album(s) PWR UP and I only want the song name as the status.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.id === '792250171320434688') {
    if (message.author.id === '403657714812715008') {

const ms = message.content
db.set('sotd_', ms)
let so = db.get('sotd_')
    client.user.setActivity(so, { type: "PLAYING"})
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is somewhere with quick.db because as far as I can tell the discord.js part is correct. My suggestion is to try the following:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.id === '792250171320434688' && message.author.id === '403657714812715008') {
    const ms = message.content
    client.user.setActivity(ms, { type: "PLAYING"})
    db.set('sotd_', ms)
  }
});
```

This way you eliminate possible errors when trying to get the data from the database. And then if you want to get the last status from quick.db do something like

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  const lastStatus = db.get('sotd_');
  client.user.setActivity(lastStatus, { type: "PLAYING"});
});
```